# HLS Stream Not Found (404) & VIDEOJS Error: Media Could Not Be Loaded (CODE:4)

Tags: html, nginx, videojs, hls

Estoy intentando reproducir un stream HLS desde la URL https://transmision.omnivision.com.sv/hls/stream.m3u8, pero obtengo un error 404 (Not Found).

https://transmision.omnivision.com.sv/

El reproductor de video (VIDEOJS) muestra el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported. bt {code: 4, message: 'The media could not be loaded, either because the …rk failed or because the format is not supported.'}
```

- He intentado reproducir el stream en diferentes navegadores, pero el error persiste.
- Mediante VLC si puedo bajar el video y va perfectamente.
- He incluido mi configuración RTMP a continuación.

  ```
     rtmp {
     server {
     listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
     chunk_size 4000;

      application show {
      live on;
      # Turn on HLS
      hls on;
      hls_path /nginx/hls/;
      hls_fragment 3;
      hls_playlist_length 60;
      # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
      deny play all;
      }
     }
    }
  ```

He verificado que el archivo stream.m3u8 y los fragmentos HLS se están generando correctamente. Sin embargo, cuando intento reproducir el archivo stream.m3u8 en un reproductor de video, obtengo un error 404.

¿He configurado algo mal en mi configuración RTMP?

Cualquier ayuda sería muy apreciada.